# How can I do a popup menu without right click using awt or swing?

Tags: java, swing, awt, contextmenu, popupmenu

I would like to program a popup menu similar to the context menu in java using AWT or Swing, however I need to display when typing a key, for example "."
I was looking por context menu but it needs right click.
¿How can I do it? Any idea...
Thanks.

Comment: And which framework ?

Comment: AWT, Swing, JavaFX, SWT....?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @MadProgrammer  [GWT as well ;)](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/07/context-menu-or-right-click-handler-in.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking the tour, I would like use AWT or Swing.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Was racking my brain for a few more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), in particular [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup)

Basically, you need to register a key binding against the component for the specified key, and when it's corresponding `actionPerformed` event is triggered, show the popup menu...

```
InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap am = getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD, 0), "popup");
am.put("popup", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        popup.pack();
        Dimension popupSize = popup.getPreferredSize();
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int x = (width - popupSize.width) / 2;
        int y = (height - popupSize.height) / 2;

        popup.show(TestPane.this, x, y);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted, after reading both references I have tested and works perfectly. I'm going to put the popup in the position of the cursor and I'll show the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can Add key listener and on key presss
please make sure with conditioned that "." key is pressed, in that block make auto key press event by Using Robot class for content Menu key button.

Or you can make right click button event.